# How to prevent group creation in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I have setup GitLab 7.12 in my firm. But users start creating groups (and groups and groups ...) and it will become a total mess very soon.
Does anyone know how to restrict groups creation to administrators of the platform ?

The idea is to have people creating projects in their personal space, and reserving groups for official ones.

Comment: Users going crazy creating groups is a real issue, isn't it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For an Omnibus install, the correct place is:

```
   /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
      gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_can_create_group'] = false
```

Then you'll need to execute `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `sudo gitlab-ctl restart` to apply the changes.

Comment: Any users who were created prior to this setting will inherit the ability to create group. So you may have to update the user settings individually as per @stuart's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33278917/1565056. Or remove the user from admin control panel if the user has no repositories(not recommended though).

Comment: Note that this solution is deprecated after Gitlab version 15.5 and invalid after version 16.0
One should use the UI or API on Gitlab >15.4.
See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#prevent-new-users-from-creating-top-level-groups

Answer (score 6):

1. Enter the Admin control panel
2. Select 'Users'
3. Select the user(s) in question and click 'Edit'
4. Scroll down to 'Access' and un-tick 'Can Create Group'

If you want to disable group creation for new users, at the moment you will have to edit the `gitlab.yml`, specifically the setting `default_can_create_group`, and set it to `false`.

See [gitlab.yml#L63@712d1768](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L63).

Answer (score 6):

For existing users, you can also use the following command on gitlab-rails console:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.update_all can_create_group:false
```

Answer (score 2):

And for old users, use something like (in rails console):

```
irb(main):012:0> @users.each do |u|
irb(main):013:1*  u.can_create_group= false
irb(main):014:1> u.save
irb(main):015:1> end
```

Answer (score 2):

For old users, the [GitLab Users API: User modification](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#user-modification) (a REST API) can also be used for this purpose (set the value of `can_create_group` to `false`) and can be easily used for bulk changes in a for loop:

```
curl --request PUT https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/users/:id?can_create_group=false
```

**Note:** Please have a look at available authentication methods at [GitLab API Authentication](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#authentication).

Answer (score 1):

[GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#admin-area-setting-to-prevent-users-from-creating-groups) (October 2022) can help:

> ### Admin Area setting to prevent users from creating groups
>
> GitLab administrators can now use the Admin Area to disable users’ permission to create top-level groups. Previously, administrators with access to the instance’s file system could change this setting only in the `gitlab.rb` file.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#prevent-users-from-creating-top-level-groups) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/367754).

---

[issue 367754](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/367754): "**Shift option to prevent users from creating groups to Instance Admin UI**", resolved with [MR 2763](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/-/merge_requests/2763):

> ### Deprecate `default_can_create_group` setting
>
> In [MR 96746](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/96746) (merged), we are migrating the setting `default_can_create_group` and its current value from the configuration file to the UI/API and hence this setting cannot be controlled via the configuration file anymore.

And:

> Make this setting available in `ApplicationSetting`, so that an Admin can control this setting via the UI/API and does not have to change the value in the `gitlab.yml` file anymore.
>
> Moving this setting to `ApplicationSetting` would also mean that GitLab admins won't have to restart the instance for the change to take effect.

---

Hence [the notice](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/-/blob/b3747c0fa8597ff73685f2421cbc4b3e42244df7/templates/NOTES.txt#L138):

> `global.appConfig.defaultCanCreateGroup` setting has been deprecated.
>
> Starting with GitLab 15.5, this setting cannot be controlled via the configuration file anymore.
> Follow the steps at [Account and limit settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#prevent-users-from-creating-top-level-groups), to configure this setting via the Admin UI or the API.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to helm deployment, changing this on the config is not available anymore, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/-/blob/master/templates/NOTES.txt#L138

```
`global.appConfig.defaultCanCreateGroup` setting has been deprecated. Starting with GitLab 15.5, this setting cannot be controlled via the configuration file anymore. Follow the steps at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#prevent-users-from-creating-top-level-groups, to configure this setting via the Admin UI or the API.
```